# Get sum of all the data inside an multidimensional array recursively :

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array :

```
Array
(
    [self] => Folder A
    [my_data] => Array
        (
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [self] => Folder AA
            [my_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object()
                )
            [20] => Array
                (
                    [self] => Folder AA
                    [my_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object()
                        )
                    [21] => Array
                )
```

I want to get the total number of records in of the present in '`my_data`'. For this I've created this function that call recursively to add the count  :

```
function getDocumentCount($tab, $count = 0) {
    foreach ($tab as $subTabKey => $subTabValue) {
        if ($subTabKey == 'my_data') {
            $count += count($subTabValue);
        }
        if ( count($tab) > 2 && $subTabKey != 'self' && $subTabKey != 'my_data' ) {
            $count += getDocumentCount($subTabValue, $count);
        }
    }

    return $count;
}
```

But this function always returning 0. The above example should return 2

Edit : This should return 5 but its returning 9

```
Array
(
    [self] => Main Folder 22
    [my_data] => Array
        (
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [self] => New Sub
            [my_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object()
                    [1] => stdClass Object()
                )
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [self] => sub folder 21
            [my_data] => Array
                (
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [self] => sub folder 211
                    [my_data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object()
                            [1] => stdClass Object()
                            [2] => stdClass Object()
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just calculated the first dimension of the array which the length of my_data is 0, so the $count is 0. Though you also calculated the inner dimmension of the array, but you didnot sum the output of them. You have to also sum the output of the inner output.

```
function getDocumentCount($tab, &$count) {
    foreach ($tab as $subTabKey => $subTabValue) {
        if ($subTabKey == 'my_data') {
            $count += count($subTabValue);
        }
        if ( count($tab) > 2 && $subTabKey != 'self' && $subTabKey != 'my_data' ) {
            getDocumentCount($subTabValue, $count);
        }
    }
}
```

use it with:

```
$count = 0;
getDocumentCount($tab, $count);
echo $count;
```

Comment: It is not working for the next example. Can you please have a look on that and guide me through this

Comment: @pkdq I've edited it. check it now. hold a while, I need edit it more

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. Eagerly waiting for the solution

Comment: @pkdq check it now

Comment: Thank you very much Kris. You are a life savior. Apart from your solution I want to ask how should I improve my array and looping logic ?

Comment: @dave no, when you define a function, you can set the parameter as reference. When you call it, you cannot pass parameter as &$xx but $xx for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the result of the call to `getDocumentCount()` to your count. Try changing the sixth line of your function to:

```
$count += getDocumentCount($subTabValue, $count);
```

Does that fix your problem?